# Error messages with piping terminal output into Qt GUI

Tags: c++, qt

Sorry about the other duplicate post. The one I was referred to helped out a lot but it isn't compiling.

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess;
connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(updateText()));
proc->start("pathToScript");
```

The second line gives me this error,

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
```

and the third gives me this one,

```
error: 'proc' does not name a type
```

Edit: The rest of my code.

ThiWindow.h:

```
#ifndef THIWINDOW_H
#define THIWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class ThiWindow;
}

class ThiWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ThiWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ThiWindow();

signals:
    void readyRead();


private slots:
    void updateText();

private:
    Ui::ThiWindow *ui;

};
```

ThiWindow.cpp:

```
#endif // THIWINDOW_H
#include "thiwindow.h"
#include "ui_thiwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>

QProcess *proc = new QProcess;
connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(updateText()));
proc->start("pathToScript");

ThiWindow::ThiWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ThiWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ThiWindow::~ThiWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}




void ThiWindow::updateText()
{
    QString appendText(proc->readAll());
    ui->textEdit->append(appendText);

}
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.cpp"
#include <QApplication>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow qw;
        qw.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Please Help,

Brooks Rady

Comment: I doubt the code you show us here, is your real code, which actually fails. Because the code here is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MOC file generation defines your class as a Qt enabled object.

This allows you to use the function `connect` without a namespace prefix. You're using it in the "generic zone", where the `connect` object isn't defined, which is why you're getting the `(` error.

If I were you, I'd move

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess;
connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(updateText()));
proc->start("pathToScript");
```

within your constructor. It should then work.

Answer (score 0):

Put QProcess *proc into private section of mainwindow.h. After that you need to allocate memory(proc = new QProcess;) in MainWindow constructor and SIGNAL/SLOT you need to realize in constructor too. 
Sorry for my English!